# How can i overide and handle memory issues?

Tags: asp.net, winforms

Developed in Visual Studio 2010, Windows Forms Application:

My program uses a 3rd party dll that causes memory leaks.  I very frequently receive the message: (The instruction at “0x100684ac” referenced memory at “0x2d1c40ac” could not be "read").  Once I click "OK" it ends the program.

Is there a way to handle this error programatically?  I handle all other errors like this:

```
     Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private Sub MyApplication_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs) Handles Me.UnhandledException
            'LOG ERROR
                helper.logerror("whatever the error msg") 
     End Sub
```

When this memory error occurs, I would like to have control.  So how do I handle/capture this error like I do with other errors (code above). FYI: Try, Catch does not work. I just need the program to End and restart itself.  I know this isn't "best practice" but I need a quick solution to restart the program in the mean time.

Answer (score 2):

You can't control things outside of your control.

This other DLL is trashing memory. It's broken. You can't fix it.

Comment: i understand that i cannot fix it the 3rd party dll, but can i control or handle the error?

Comment: No, that's my whole point. The DLL _is_ the error. It's broken. You have no way to know how badly it has screwed up memory. There is no upper limit on how screwed up things can be. There's no one particular "error". You're just seeing things _after_ all of the damage has been done.